# Lightning Component, retrieving lookup record values in controller

Tags: javascript, salesforce, field, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to convert a simple OnClick Javascript button to Lightning.  This OnClick is pretty simple, it just opens a URL, but it uses a value on a parent record as part of the URL. ie, a button on the Opportunity Object that will grab part of the URL from it's parent Account's This_Field__c field:

```
    window.open('https://www.salesforce.com/'+'{!Account.This_Field__c}'+'/info');
```

So if the value on the field was XYZ, this would open the page https://www.salesforce.com/XYZ/info

What's the easiest way to get the value of Account.This_Field__c in a lightning component?

Considered using an Apex controller but that seems like overkill.  Tried force:recordData, didn't seem to work, possibly because of it beign on a parent record.  We don't want more fields on the Opportunity, otherwise I might try a formula.

window.open('https://www.salesforce.com/'+'{!Account.This_Field__c}'+'/info');

If the value on the field was XYZ, this would open the page https://www.salesforce.com/XYZ/info

Answer (score 1):

`<force:recordData>` does support relationship fields, although this fact is buried in the [Lightning Data Service Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) page in the documentation:

> Lightning Data Service supports spanned fields with a maximum depth of five levels.

Here's a very simple example:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
    <aura:attribute name="targetRecord" type="Object" />

    <force:recordData 
                      recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                      fields="Account.Website"
                      targetFields="{! v.targetRecord }"
                      />

    <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.targetRecord.Account.Website)) }">
        <a href="{! v.targetRecord.Account.Website }">Account Website</a>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

An Apex controller will also work, but adds complexity because you'd have to write Apex, JavaScript, and Apex unit tests.

The simplest solution is a `HYPERLINK()` formula on the Opportunity.